Vue 2 + Axios - Show / Hide div as result of Axois request result
I have a div in my html page
<div class="ui-alert" v-show="isCaptchaError"> ... </div>

isCaptchaError - initialized in my Vue instance:
const form = new Vue({
    el: '#main-form',
    data: {
        isCaptchaError: false,
    },

In watcher on my input I'm creating axios request and set this.isCaptchaError = true
const form = new Vue({
    el: '#main-form',
...
    watch: {
        phoneNumber(val) {
                        axios({
                            method: 'post',
                            url: '/rest/client',
                            data: ajaxRequest
                        }).then(function (response) {
                            this.isCaptchaError = true;
                        })
        }
    }

But div is not show.
If I set this.isCaptchaError = true on any button click then div shows
How to hide / show div after result of axios request?

it's a problem with this not being the scope of the component.  use arrow function instead .then(response => {

I'm sure that understand you correctly. Pls show example of correct solution

This case .then(response => {this.isCaptchaError = true;} doesn't work either

in that case, add a .catch - perhaps the axios call is rejecting, and thus .then is never called - actually, can you confirm that the axios request is being made at all?

Give a try to the following
async phoneNumber(val) {
  const response = await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/rest/client',
    data: ajaxRequest
  })
  this.isCaptchaError = true
}

Not sure what is your val or your response doing in your snippet of code but this would work well. Feel free to edit with more details/errors if you still have some issues with this.
This docs' page is still very relevant and useful.

Thank you for doc reference. It was very useful :)
